# TypeError: Input z must be 2D, not 3D

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

I have the following code:

```
x = np.arange(0,4)
y = np.arange(6,10)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
print(a.shape,x.shape,y.shape)
plt.contour([X,Y,],a)
plt.show()
```

which gives the following output:

```
(4, 4) (4,) (4,)
TypeError: Input z must be 2D, not 3D
```

Clearly, the array `a` is 2-D as when printing the shape I get `(4,4)`. Looking at the documentation, it also gives the syntax to be `contour([X, Y,] Z, [levels], **kwargs)`, which I believe I've followed (except for the comma after `[X,Y,]` but when I cut that out I get a syntax error so I'm assuming it's a typo but I could be wrong). Putting levels in/taking them out makes no difference.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the shape of your arrays, the problem isn't with the shape of `a` as you expected, but with the fact that you shouldn't put `X` and `Y` in a list when calling [`plt.contour`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contour.html).
I guess you should write :

```
plt.contour(X, Y, a)
```

Note that the function signature `contour([X, Y,] Z, [levels], **kwargs)` mean that `X` and `Y` (as well as `levels`) are optional parameters (not that they should be put in a list when calling the function).
So it is also valid, for example, to call `plt.contour` like so :

```
plt.contour(a)
```